# (Eclipse) The value for the useBean class attribute is invalid

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have been looking for ages now but none of the solutions google offered me helped for my situation.

I wrote a simple JSP-File and only tried to use the "useBean" statement (that's the line where the error occurs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="package1.TestBean" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<jsp:useBean id="test" class="package1.TestBean" />

</body>
</html>
```

My JavaBean is an empty class but has an empty constructor without parameters:

```
package package1;

public class TestBean {

    public TestBean() {

    }

}
```

I created the class by right-clicking the project folder and then using New->Class.

So as I already said, the error occurs in the following line:

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="package1.TestBean" />
```

And the error message is (as already named in the title) "The value for the useBean class attribute package1.TestBean is invalid."

Please help me! :-(

Edit: A friend of mine tried the same, on his computer it works. Now he sent me his project folder, I imported it and it works, too!?!?!?

Comment: Have you place the compile .class file under classes directory?  package1.TestBean.class file in `<Application_Base>/<application_name>/WEB-INF/classes/user/
directory`

Comment: What kind of project are you in? Is the error message showing up in the Problems view or when you run the page?

Comment: I did not place any file anywhere. I just created the files (I'm working with Eclipse). Is it really necessary to compile the classes and put the files manually in any folder? The class is located in package1 which is located (in eclipse) in the src-folder of the project.

Comment: I think I found the solution on my own: I formerly installed an other version of Tomcat. In my JRE there was a link to the old Tomcat folder (precisely: the location of the servlet-api.jar) I fixed the broken link and now it works! Thanks anyway for your efforts!! You're awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: There was a conflict between two Tomcat installations. See comments on Question for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

stop Tomcat,go to Project-->Clean ->select the respective project->click clean. start Tomcat again